# Python Получить содержимое Тэга

Tags: python, selenium, tag

Есть код страницы. Вот часть из него:

```
<div class="table_cell width16">
  <div>Счет: 1-4</div>
</div>
```

Хочу выгрузить значение "Счет 1-4".

Скрипт

```
score = browser.find_element_by_class_name('width16').find_element_by_tag_name('div')
Print(score.text)
```

почему-то выдает пустое значение. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

```
score = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "table_cell width16")]')
Print(score.text)
```

Comment: К сожалению, проблема осталась :(

Comment: а сайт можно, где пытаетесь?

Comment: https://xscore.win/xg-statistics/view.php?country=291

Comment: Если что, могу уже написанный код скинуть.

Comment: Следующий код у меня работает. Вывод: 1-4. Разворачивал вручную, если что
`from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\\Python37\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://xscore.win/xg-statistics/view.php?country=291')
score = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "table_cell width16")]')
print(score.text)`

Comment: Да. Если вручную раскрывать, отображается. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @МаксСалихов 
Чтобы не раскрывать вручную:
Первая строчка - получает список всех кнопок со страницы, вторая строчка, кликает по кнопке из списка, в данном случае раскроет Brighton - MC
`buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class, "btn_toggle")]')
buttons[1].click()`

Answer (score 0):

Давайте упростим вам жизнь. Для поиска элемента вам не нужно отдельными функциями `find_element_by..` "указывать путь" к нужному вам элементу. То есть, то, что вы записали в своём коде двумя `find_element_by..`:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('width16').find_element_by_tag_name('div')
```

Можно записать одним, используя `xpath`:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="table_cell width16"]/div')
print(element.text)
```

Так же, есть ещё несколько десятков способов найти ваш элемент применяя только один `xpath`, но для удобства просто покажу несколько примечательных.

Если в родительском `div` в классе `table_cell width16` есть часть которая генерируется или меняется по каким-нибудь неведомым правилам, вы это класс можете найти по частичному совпадению. В `xpath` такой поиск выполняет функция `contains()`:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "width16")]/div')
print(element.text)
```

В этом примере мы нашли наш родительский `div` по содержанию в теге `class` строки `width16`, и не важно какие ещё будут имена классов в этом теге.

По этой же логике вы можете сразу найти элемент с текстом `Счет 1-4` минуя любые родительские элементы и используя для этого слово `Счет`:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()[contains(., 'Счет')]]")
print(element.text)
```

Так же, возможным логическим упрощением может стать операнд `*` который используется вместо указателя на конкретный элемент - `div`. То есть, если вы не уверены, что вы ищите конкретно `div`, а текстовое поле может быть к примеру в `span` или любом другом элементе, то вы можете использовать `*` как указатель на `любой элемент`:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(., 'Счет')]]")
print(element.text)
```

Ну и конечно же, если вы хотите развиваться в такой сфере дальше, то крайне рекомендую вам почитать про `xpath` или `css-селекторы`. Это два похожих друг на друга `инструмента` по навигации в `xml` коде (html страница как раз и есть xml код). Откроете для себя массу интересных и упрощающих возможностей. Просто начните интересоваться))) Удачи!